# How can I receive a warning when Google Drive creates a [conflict] file?

Tags: google-drive

Occasionally Google Drive is conflicted about which file to keep, so it keeps both, and renames one, appending its filename with "[Conflict]."  Does anyone know of solutions that would notify me whenever this occurs?  Certain files are critical, so when such a conflict occurs, I'd like to resolve it immediately.  Perhaps a built in Windows utility, or a (preferably free) third party program?

I'm running Windows 10, x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is wondering, I accomplished this by using AutoIt to create an EXE that will scan the folder in-question and prompt if any filenames contain the string "Conflict." I then used Windows Task Scheduler to run that program once a day. I'm going to look into event triggers in Task Scheduler to see if I can get the program to run more frequently (e.g. any time Google Chrome is opened).

This can all probably be accomplished with some Power Shell scripting as well, but I'm not too familiar with that.